# Error: UNIQUE constraint failed: gpkg_contents.identifier

Tags: sqlite

Why do I get "Error: UNIQUE constraint failed: gpkg_contents.identifier" error when trying to:

```sql
UPDATE gpkg_contents SET identifier = 'labs' WHERE lower(table_name) = lower('labss') AND identifier = 'labss';
```

although I am not violating that unique constraint:

```sql
sqlite> select table_name,identifier from gpkg_contents ;
table_name  identifier
----------  ----------
dims        dims      
pol         pol       
parcel-lin  parcel-lin
parcel      parcel    
grid        grid      
bounds      bounds    
labss       labss
```

setting the identifier to something other than 'labs' works fine. e.g.:

```sql
UPDATE gpkg_contents SET identifier = 'labs2' WHERE lower(table_name) = lower('labss') AND identifier = 'labss';
```

the table schema is as the following:

```sql
sqlite> .schema gpkg_contents
CREATE TABLE gpkg_contents (table_name TEXT NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,data_type TEXT NOT NULL,identifier TEXT UNIQUE,description TEXT DEFAULT '',last_change DATETIME NOT NULL DEFAULT (strftime('%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%fZ','now')),min_x DOUBLE, min_y DOUBLE,max_x DOUBLE, max_y DOUBLE,srs_id INTEGER,CONSTRAINT fk_gc_r_srs_id FOREIGN KEY (srs_id) REFERENCES gpkg_spatial_ref_sys(srs_id));
```

[The sqlite database file](http://easyupload.io/xhg7va)

Comment: The code works fine: https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/gF7FQr8xdn8rntCiupVozM/0 So you must have a constraint.

Comment: @forpas thanks. Please take a look at the file itself. Perhaps the db file is corrupt?! https://easyupload.io/xhg7va

Comment: I did not find anything that would justify this error message!

Comment: These two queries (in DB Browser) on that database give interesting results: `select identifier from gpkg_contents` and (far more interesting) `select * from gpkg_contents
where identifier = 'labs'`

Comment: @DinoCoderSaurus thanks. I think I have corrupted the database. The main reason could be simultaneous updates of the database without proper releasing of the locks (transactions)

Comment: @DinoCoderSaurus I get `database disk image is malformed`!!! for the 2nd query and the 1st returns `'labs'`!!!